# Javascript - Grid of Checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am about to start a task where I will have a grid of checkboxes which will allow users to select all of the checkboxes, some of them or none of them. I will also add a few conditionals where you can select a checkbox if you have selected the one above it directly and deselect them if the checkbox above has been selected.

Before I write this I was wondering if there is something that is already out there than can do this or something similar? Or at the very least something I can build on. I have already bing'ed and Google'd - but nothing has come up for me.

I would also appreciate implementation advice as this I don't want this to be a messy job and I can already imagine myself getting into a mess!

I would really love it if there was something out there for JQuery as I already make use of this.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [this jquery plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/checkboxes/), with a little adjusting it could do what you want...

Comment: This will actually prove useful thank you. I can make use of some of its functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You're better off rolling your own. Sounds like a pretty specific set of requirements, and I doubt you'll find anything that does this easily, and even if you did, it would take more time to figure out how the API works and fit it to your needs than to just write the thing yourself.

Comment: You are correct, its too specific - I will be creating my own but making use of the plugin Bishiboosh suggested - it will only do 10% of what I need but that's better than nothing! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about jQuery, however [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/) offers a grid with checkboxes.  You create a grid using a CheckboxSelectionModel.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [JSLightGrid](https://github.com/chanakyachatterjee/JSLightGrid). Though it's not JQuery rather pure javascript but is pretty good for column templates, performance, responsiveness and very light weight